# Using Pointers In Conjunction With Classes Returns Garbage Values

Tags: c++

This is code from a quiz earlier today. Language: C++.

```
class Shape
{ 
protected:
int *x;
int *y;
public:
void draw()
    {
      //we were supposed to add random code here.  
    }
};
```

We were asked to create an overloaded operator of our choice and implement it in main. I was a little intimidated by the pointers so I decided to create a constructor like so:

```
class Shape
{ 
protected:
int *x;
int *y;
public:
void draw()
    {
       cout<<*x<<endl;
    }
    Shape(){};
    Shape{int a, int b)
    {
        x = &a; //this I thought would allow *x to act just like a normal variable. 
        y = &b; 
    }
    //code for operator overloading.
};
```

I was under the impression that I had aced the quiz but when I went ahead and tried implementing it on my computer at home, I realized that the draw function returns garbage values/memory addresses. Everything else suffers as a result. Can you please tell me why this is happening? Does it have to do with the scope of the pointers? I want to be able to use pointers as regular variables. Just a student. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `x = &a;` assigns the address of a temporary to `x`. `a` doesn't exist after the constructor completed. Dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a and b is put on the stack and assigning x and y pointer to the address of a and b. This will make x and y point somewhere in the stack, so the value of *x (and *y) is whatever happen to be on the stack at those addresses.

Answer (score 3):

If this is C++, which is what it looks like, then your problem is that you're assigning pointers to the address of constructor's parameters.

Constructor parameters are created when the constructor is called, and destroyed when the constructor is destroyed, thereby, your pointers will point to garbage after the constructor is destroyed.  Assign your pointers to non-function-local variables.